# Too many ImageButton makes the app crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

in my Android app I have to make visible about 43 ImageButton in the first fragment of my tabbed activity and other different 43 in the other one. The first one works fine, it's when I added the second fragment that the app crashed. Not only that if I click on one of my ImageButton if I want to show a particular image never used before the app crash.

The images in my drawable folder are 1MB (of 159 images) so I don't really know if it's too much.

This are the errors meggages that appears:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.myname.hira_kana, PID: 6672 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Failed to allocate a 9000012 byte allocation with 204192 free bytes
>   and 199KB until OOM at
>   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>   at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>   at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771) at
>   android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525) at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:30)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:372)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:66)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:192)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) at
>   layout.frkata.onCreateView(frkata.java:56) at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>   at

(I cuoldn't post all of the errors because the site think it's spam)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are attempting to allocate 9000012 bytes. That is equivalent to a 1500x1500 pixel image. **This is much too large**. "The images in my drawable folder are 1MB" -- that is meaningless. What matters is the size in memory, and images on disk are stored in compressed form.

Answer (score 2):

Paste this in manifest file:-

android:largeHeap="true"

Also read this:http://dwij.co.in/increase-heap-size-of-android-application/

Example:-

```
<application 
    android:name=".MyApplication"
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="Mall" android:largeHeap="true" 
     android:logo="@drawable/logo_for_up"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: this should be avoided as a solution for anything except when really necessary. you should try to learn and fix the problem, not put a bandage and say it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because your images might be very large. Please create bitmap with small height and width and then use those images in Imageview.
You can use following code to create small bitmap:

```
 bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, outWidth, outHeight, true);
```